# XML drawable composed of png and overlay

Tags: android, xml, button, png, drawable

I have a png button, which is enabled, non-pressed. When user click the button, I want only to darken the png. I need something like this:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  //normal button with background my_button.png
        <item 
            android:state_enabled="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/my_button"   //my_button.png
            />
  //pressed button with background my_button.png overlayed by 50% black
        <item 
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:state_enabled="true"    
            >
            <RelativeLayout 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <bitmap  android:src="@drawable/my_button"/>
              <color android:color="#00000088"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </item>      
    </selector>
```

Is there some way how to do that? Or do I must have another png file?

Answer (score 11):

In my_button_bg.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

button_normal is a png

button_pressed is an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/btn_bg_pressed_mask"/>
</layer-list>
```

where btn_bg_pressed_mask is a color:

```
<color name="btn_bg_pressed_mask">#19000000</color>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_button" />
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item
                android:state_pressed="true"
                android:state_enabled="true">
                <color android:color="#00000088" />
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the items in the selector XML make a difference. The first match is what is going to get displayed. As you see in marmor's answer, the normal state  of the button is listed at the end.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you are using 9-patch images (.9.png), the color will only be applied to the content area. So if you want the color to be overlayed over the whole image, make sure to mark the whole image as the content area.